# wp_cache_set() or wp_cache_add()

Tags: cache

That's the question!

There's not much explanation on [`wp_cache_set()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cache_set) an even less for [`wp_cache_add()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cache_add).

What should I use in which circumstances?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According with [WP Object API documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) both functions accepts these arguments:

- `$key`: the key to indicate the value.
- `$data`: the value you want to store.
- `$group`: (optional) this is a way of grouping data within the cache. Allows you to use the same key across different groups.
- `$expire`: (optional) this defines how many seconds to keep the cache for. Only applicable to some functions. Defaults to 0 (as long as possible).

The difference is:

- `wp_cache_add()`: if the cache key doesn't exist, it add the cache data. If the cache key already exists, the function returns false and does nothing with the cached data.
- `wp_cache_set()`: same as above but if the cache key already exists, the cache data is overwritten.

Comment: and why didn't I RTFM? Thank you!