# What's the uses of wp_cache_set() or wp_cache_add()?

Tags: php, functions

I see many theme uses wp_cache_set() and wp_cache_add() functions and i can't understand how this function works.

How are these functions useful for WordPress developers?

Comment: Start with [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp\_cache\_set() or wp\_cach\_add()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206075/wp-cache-set-or-wp-cach-add)